# session value is not the correct value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass a session variable from one page to another but it keeps returning the same value of '2' I am not entirely sure where this value is coming from though.

I am setting the value inside of a funtion to get the id of the value from the dashboard set into the session.

```
function listDashboards() {
global $conn;


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dashboards";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                $_SESSION['dansDashboardId'] = $row["dashboard_id"]; // HERE

                echo $_SESSION['dansDashboardId']; // AND HERE

                echo '<div class="dashboardListRow">';
                echo '<a href="../index.php">' . $row["dashboard_name"] . '</a>';
                echo '<button>View Dashboard</button>';         
                echo '<a href="dashboard.php?dashboard_id=' . $row["dashboard_id"] . '">' . '<button>Manage Dashboard</button></a>';            
                echo '</div>';

            }
        } else{
            header('Location: create-dashboard.php');
        }

    }
```

When I click on the link to the `,,/index.php` file inside of the loop I want to then echo out the session variable on that page but ist just keeps returning '2'

`$dashboardIdNew = $_SESSION['dansDashboardId'];`

`echo $dashboardIdNew` just returns `2`

However, if I echo out that session inside of the loop it returns the correct values

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Start here: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Are you using `start_session()` where you're trying to retrieve the values?

Comment: @scottevans93 I am yes

Comment: @danjbh What happens when you do `var_dump($_SESSION);` on your index page?

Comment: @scottevans93 on both links i get ` ["dansDashboardId"]=> string(1) "2" }` there are two links one with an ID of 1 and one with and ID of 2

Comment: You're setting a $_SESSION var inside a while loop. so it is likely getting set and reset multiple times.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter if I put this anywhere outside of the loop it returns back as `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I echo out that session inside of the loop it returns the correct values

As you go around the loop, you set the variable to **each** `$row["dashboard_id"];` **in turn**.

You echo it out each time you set it.

You therefore see each value you give it.

---

> When I click on the link to the ,,/index.php file inside of the loop I want to then echo out the session variable on that page but ist just keeps returning '2'

That would be the **last** `$row["dashboard_id"];` in the result set. i.e. the last value you set that variable to.

Comment: How do I go about returning the correct value and not the last value of the rows?

Comment: @danjbh — Don't use sessions. Store the results in the link. Read the result from `$_GET`. (And don't wrap the link with a button, that's invalid).

Comment: I moved away from GET because of how my ids are set the users can just switch between urls by altering the url

Comment: @danjbh — If you want the user to pick something, then you have to provide them the ability to pick it. You can't avoid the user having control over what they ask the server to do. Use authentication and authorisation to determine if they are allowed to pick a given ID after you've received the request to pick it.

Comment: Without knowing any of what Im doing its almost impossible for you to suggest that. Im trying to find a solution that prevents users from simply altering the urls to change what they see.

Comment: Use a form with a hidden input. That will keep it out of the URL. It won't stop the user from changing it with a trivial amount of effort though. You need authn/authz.

Comment: "Without knowing any of what Im doing its almost impossible for you to suggest that" — If that is true … then stop asking [XY Questions](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: When I added a hidden field and posted that across to the next page the urls added ?= to it, very strange...?

Comment: You can use POST instead of GET to "hide" (not really but for noob users) the parameter

Comment: how would I include a POST method into what I am doing though and out put it at the other end? so if I click on index.php how do I post out the value to the index.php file

Comment: for each row you create a `<form method="POST" action="index.php"><input type="hidden" name="dashboard_id" value="<?php $row['dashboard_id']?>"> ...<button type="submit"> </form>`

Comment: or with javascript, you check what button is clicked, then you set a hidden form value, then you submit a form

Comment: So there are lots of ways to "hide" the value from the user … with varying degrees of complexity … but they are all as effective as throwing a sheet over it. The user can easily remove the sheet and change it.